# Where should a mac os x app store its temporary data

Tags: cocoa

I am new to mac os x. Is there an application specific folder allocated by the mac os x when it gets installed to store its temporary files ? like in windows there is an  app data folder for the apps to save their data and system temporary file folders are different .

Comment: /tmp ? is that recommended ? or NSTemporaryDirectory as Tom said in the answer below ? Is there any standard ?

Comment: /tmp is the BSD/Unix temporary folder. NSTemporaryDirectory is always the best way. You could make your own and simply clean up afterwards, but why invent this all over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just use `NSTemporaryDirectory()` to get a temporary directory. You should create your own app-specific subdirectory below this path.

Comment: The documentation says NSTemppraryDirectory() may return nil, any ideas why ?

Comment: No. I've never seen it happen. You should, of course, check the return value in any case.